# System wide networking excptions handling

Tags: android, android-layout, design-patterns, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I am writing an Android client/server app.
Was wondering if there is some kind of pattern that is recommended for handling networking issues on a app wide level.

The app has several activities/fragments and quite a few operations can be done against the server side (User triggered and automated). 
I want to be able to let the user know when the server is unreachable or when there is some kind of networking problem, in a way that allow him to retry/cancel the request that encountered the error.

Raising the error message on screen as a popup or as a panel that will appear from bottom/top will not be an issue. But how can I implement a 'retry' button or choose where to fallback in case of an error? Because it's app wide and I want to handle it on the networking layer level I have now way knowing in what screen the user is in and what is the UI status.

The UI uses AsyncTask instances to initiate all networking operations.

Any idea/pattern/example will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guideline.

Let's assume you had following classes:

- Classes which run network requests
- NetworkCommand (this has all the needed information of the request (GET,POST,PUT... url, parameters etc.)
- NetworkCommandManager (this does the HTTP request based on NetworkCommand objects data)

So when manager runs any network command with `AsyncTask/Thread` it gets notified of the result and which network command was it. So you can handle errors there and show a dialog that it failed, allow user to retry and you run the same network command again with manager.